# ImportError: No module named celery for Celery 3.1 and Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery

Using Python 2.7 and Celery 3.1.25 on Windows, when we run the Celery worker using

```
celery -A proj worker -l info
```

we get the error

```
ImportError: No module named celery
```

**Problem:** The worker stops working when we

- changed the name of the file `celeryApp.py` from `celery.py`
- changed the import statement in `tasks.py` from `from .celery import app` to `from celeryApp import app`.

Why is this happening? How can we fix the problem?

**Directory structure**

```
/proj/__init__.py
/proj/celeryApp.py
/proj/tasks.py
```

**/proj/celeryApp.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', 
    broker='amqp://jack:jack@192.168.1.26:5672//',
    backend='amqp://',
    include=['proj.tasks'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

**/proj/tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celeryApp import app

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Answer (score 1):

When starting a celery worker, you should name the app to match the python file where the celery module is configured. You should start worker with

```
celery worker -l info -A tasks
```

You shouldn't name your config file to `celery.py`. This will cause problems when you start importing

```
from celery import Celery
```

Your file should be named something else but not `celery.py`.

Also in your config file there is no need to add

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

If you are going to explicitly include `proj.tasks` make sure `proj` is in python path or you can just remove it as you are starting worker with `tasks` app.