# Celery worker not starting: "Module 'proj' has no attribute 'celery'"

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I'm using Django, Celery, and RabbitMQ. When I run `celery -A FlakeFinder worker -l INFO` from the top level directory, I get the error:

```
Usage: celery [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app': 
Unable to load celery application.
Module 'flakefinder' has no attribute 'celery'
```

If I instead run `celery -A FlakeFinder.celeryApp worker -l INFO`, I get this error in purple text:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery.backends.amqp'
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here. How can I get the celery worker running?

My folder structure looks like this:

```
. (FlakeFinder)
├── FlakeFinder
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── celeryApp.py
│   ├── secrets.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── license.txt
├── manage.py
├── scraping
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── scraper.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
```

**celeryApp.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab  # scheduler

# default django settings
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'FlakeFinder.settings')

app = Celery('FlakeFinder')
app.conf.timezone = 'UTC'
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    # executes every 1 minute
    'scraping-task-three-hr': {
        'task': 'scraping.tasks',
        'schedule': crontab()
    }
}
```

**tasks.py**

```
from scraping.scraper import *
from celeryApp import app


@app.task
def update_snow_locs():
    ...
```

Comment: Looks like the [`amqp` backend has been deprecated](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6384).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to get past this. I solved the issue by downgrading to version 4.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing name of 'celeryApp.py' to 'celery.py'

Comment: This comment advises against naming it celery.py. I used to have it as celery.py and it still didn't work when it was like that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43038088/1917407

Comment: In my sample project, if I change the name of the file containing the app to anything other than 'celery.py', I need to add 'import celery' to the `__init__.py` file.  Not clear to me why this is needed!

Comment: I changed it back to celery.py and it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

The AMQP result backend is scheduled for deprecation in version 4.0 and removal in version v5.0. Please use RPC backend or a persistent backend.

Answer (score -1):

The error seems to be quite clear.

```
from celery import Celery
from celery import task  

celery = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//') #!

import os

os.environ[ 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' ] = "proj.settings"

@task()
def add_photos_task( lad_id ):
...
```

This is what I found online with the explanation - "forgot to create a celery object in tasks.py"
But no means I am an expert in Celery Module.

Comment: This didn't solve the issue. There is no celery module "task", and even without that, adding the broker kward or the os.environ line didn't do it.

Comment: Okay, I looked deeper and found out that Calery removed the task from version 5x, maybe downgrading to version might make it work. ```pip3 install celery==4.4.2```